# KDE black screen after login, problem with Qt libraries

Tags: shell, kde, login, qt, sddm

I am using a clean OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 installation with KDE. I installed a list of packages for an application I am developing which require a number of Qt5 libraries, and for it to work, I have to load these libraries to my environment.

For this I have copied a script to my /etc/profile.d directory which runs . /opt/myapp/environment.sh. In this script there is the problematic line that appends these libraries to my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (I've tried before or after the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

The result is that I see the login screen, but after the login I just see a black screen and the cursor. Through trial and error I am certain that the Qt libraries are what causing the problem, but I don't know how to solve this. I am using `sddm` (by default) by the way.

This problem is not reproduced in other desktop environments.

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, if you *don't* run `/opt/.../environment.sh` from `profile.d`, everything works?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly. Same if I remove all the Qt libraries from the script.

Comment: @rfmodulator Upon opening the terminal after getting the black screen, I ran `plasmascreen` and got a lot of lines like this: `plasmashell: /opt/myapp/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libKF5Solid.so.5)`.

Comment: You might try running `ldconfig`.

Comment: @rfmodulator `ldconfig` didn't work, I still get the same result .